# How to substring a string without using slice and print function?

Tags: python, for-loop, substring

```
make_substring(chars: str, start: int, stop: int, step: int)-> str
```

Want a method which returns a substring of the given string that begins at the start index (inclusive) and ends at the stop index (exclusive), increasing step characters each iteration. Assume start and stop are non-negative and step is positive. Also using for loop.

```
def make_substring(chars: str, start: int, stop: int, step: int) -> str:
    c = chars
    s = ""
    if start + step < stop:
       for i in range(start, stop, step):
           s = c[start] + c[start + step]
       return s

# using test case:
make_substring("ABCD", 0, 3, 2) == "AC"
```

Comment: Don't you find it suspicious that you're not using `i` in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
s = c[start] + c[start + step]
```

keeps setting `s` to the same two characters, since `start` and `start + step` don't change in the loop. It doesn't accumulate characters, and it doesn't process the characters at index `i`.

That line should be:

```
s += c[i]
```

Using `+=` makes it append to the string, and `c[i]` is the current character from the range.

Also, get rid of the `if` statement. Even if `start + step > stop`, you should still include the character at `start` in the result.

```
def make_substring(chars: str, start: int, stop: int, step: int) -> str:
    s = ""
    for i in range(start, stop, step):
        if i >= len(chars):
            break // stop when we run out of characters
        s += chars[i]
    return s
```

There's no need for the `c` variable, you can simply use the `chars` parameter.

Comment: I tried `make_substring("ABCD", 0, 3, 2)` and it returned `AC`, just as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your posting. But when I tried to do show, it shows me a error that string index out of range.

Comment: I added a check that `i` is within the string.